# How to show the expected value of a hitting time Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

We have $W_t$ as a Brownian motion and $$T_{−a,b} = \inf \{t ≥ 0 : W_t \not\in [−a, b]\}\qquad a, b > 0$$ How do you show $\mathbb{E} (W_{T_{-a,b}}) = 0$?

Comment: I'd recommend tagging this with (probability-theory) instead of (probability).

Comment: @user38584 Done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Deduce from the optional stopping theorem that$$\mathbb{E}(W_{T_{-a,b} \wedge R})=0$$ for any $R>0$. Apply the dominated convergence theorem in order to conclude $$\mathbb{E}(W_{T_{-a,b}})=0.$$